# PHP-SDK publish link not available for public

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, publish, public

When publishing a new link, using php sdk, the link is only available for logged user, it's not publish as public.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $appId,
'secret' => $secret,
'cookie' => true
));
$user = $facebook->getUser(); // Get the UID of the connected user, or 0 if the Facebook user is not connected.

if($user == 0) {
setcookie('cod_eventos', $_POST['cod_eventos']);
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params = array('scope' => "publish_stream"));
setcookie('userlogin', 1);
echo ("<script>window.open('".$login_url."')</script>");
} else {
$page_id = $page_id;
try {
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken(); 
$attachment2 = array(
'access_token' => $access_token 
);
$page = $facebook->api('/me/accounts', 'get', $attachment2);
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
echo 'Unable to get page access token';
}
$privacy = array(
'value' => 'EVERYONE',
);
$attachment = array(
'access_token' => $page['data'][0]['access_token'],
'name' => 'Test',
'link' => 'http://www.facebook.com/',
'description' =>'Facebook',
'privacy' => json_encode($privacy),
);
try {
$facebook->api('/' . $page_id . '/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
echo '<div class="gestor_ficheiros_tipo">Event publish Facebook</div>';
} 
catch (FacebookApiException $e)
{
echo '<div class="gestor_ficheiros_tipo">'.$e->getMessage().'</div>';
}
```

After running this the content is publish, but not view-able by un-registered facebook users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was the problem, I was using facebook app in sandbox mode... :(. Once I've changed it started working perfectly

Comment: provide some line of code as to where you did the mistake so no one else repeat it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, despite what the API documentation says, the privacy setting is 'privacy_type', not 'privacy'. I found that out here on SO I think, but closed the tab so I can't immediately share the link.

Comment: Just re-tested with privacy_type and the problem remains, I guess it's something else. :(

Answer (score 0):

Check the settings on your app as well - I think it's the 'Visibility of app and posts' setting defaults to 'Friends' instead of 'Public'. Maybe that'll do it?

Comment: I think you mean is "Default Activity Privacy", am I right ? If that's it, I already have it on Public.